# how the values added to spring model class flown to view in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

IN below code, we are adding attribute to model object which is passed as argument. But how come model.addAttribute() adds the value to list.jsp .Basically i want to know how the name values passed to list.jsp

Because we are not returning model object rather returning "list". so how the value is passed to list.jsp?

```
 @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/movie")
    public class MovieController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getMovie(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {

            model.addAttribute("movie", name);
            return "list";

        }

    }
```

list.jsp is as follows

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Spring 3 MVC REST web service</h1>

    <h3>Movie Name : ${movie}</h3>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: model.addAttribute adds the object into the response object of the following page, the list.jsp can access anything in response, session, context, config, page scopes by just using ${movie} , jsp will take care of looking up all the abve mentioed scopes if you use EL (${movie} in this case)

Comment: "model.addAttribute adds the object into the response object of the following page" how does it work , may I know the documentation link to understand it more.

Comment: @user3448119 here is the link u can better understand your concept http://thespringthing.blogspot.in/2010/11/how-does-modelattribute-work.html

Comment: @henrycahrles, thanks for that, but that link talks about ModelAttribute annotation. but i am not using it in the example posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection! The DispatcherServlet do all the hard work for you. Probably the model will be an attribute of the response object (HttpServletResponse)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the View (you JSP in this particular case), you'll have available the Model object (you loaded in the controller). It will use the data inside the model to render it using EL expressions. Your view will call getters by Reflection invoking the same field name you used.

> View is where the data in the Model is rendered as the required
>   output for the client.   SpringMVC provides many implementations of
>   View to generate different output such as JSP,Excel, PDF, XML and etc.
>   DispatcherServlet will invoke render method from selected View
>   implementation to generate the output to be returned to the client.

Further [info](http://markchensblog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-spring-mvc-works.html)

Answer (score 0):

Spring adds model attributes to the `ServletRequest` attributes. See [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractView.java#L370) for details.